# Export/Import Modules in existing Personal.xlsb or create new Personal.xlsb to Clear Trash

Tags: excel, vba

I understand it is possible for my Personal.xlsb to become burdened with old cache/information from creating/editing/running/debugging too many macros and that will be cleaned by exporting and reimporting the modules.

Is it sufficient to do that in the existing Personal.xlsb, or to be extra sure it is cleaned, should I delete the existing personal.xlsb (after exporting) and create a new one to import the modules back into?  Or should the export/import be all that is necessary?

Being chicken, I would probably just rename / move the old one out of the XLSTART directory instead of actually deleting it.

Comment: Nothing to stop you going the whole way and creating a new workbook, but typically folks just export and delete the modules, then re-import to the same workbook.

Comment: WIth [MZ-Tools 8.0](https://www.mztools.com/v8/download_trial.aspx) you can right click  the project and click clean.  It's also loaded with many other feature.

Comment: @Tim Williams - thank you!

Comment: @TinMan - thank you also, but unless I am going to use all the other features, that is a lot of money for something I can do easily by export/import (that I can also automate in a macro).  But I do appreciate the response and the tip.